# How to enable the bucket replication using boto3 'put_bucket_replication' method?

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-s3, boto3

I need to enable the bucket replication for my s3 bucket.

I referred below 2 links for this and written the code (see below). But replication not enabled. But weirdly, a file created in the source bucket.

1. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_bucket_replication
2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUTreplication.html

Could anyone help me with this?

source bucket name = tst;
Destination bucket name = rst

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3',endpoint_url=S3_URL,aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_ID,aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,region_name=REGION)
s3.put_bucket_replication(Bucket='tst',ReplicationConfiguration={'Role': 'arn:aws:iam::10000003:root','Rules': [{'Status': 'Enabled','Destination': {'Bucket': 'arn:aws:s3:::rst'}}]})
```